# How to place another TextLabel in UITableViewCell's right side in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to place another Cell text in the right side of `UITableViewCell` in iOS like following pic.

[image]

How can i do that?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UITableViewCell has a property, `detailTextLabel`, which corresponds to the text label you are inquiring about. Just assign text to that label

i.e.

```
  cell.textLabel.text = @"Google";
  cell.detailTextLabel.text= @"Yesterday";
```

The little "arrow", additionally, is the accessory view on the cell

```
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

Comment: I think detailTextLabel is the under of cell.textLabel?? not in right side.

Comment: So you mean i need use with UITableViewCellStyleDefault? or UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle?

Comment: `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` will put the `detailTextLabel` under the `textLabel`. Any other style I believe will put it on the right.

Comment: Yes bro. I used with UITableViewCellStyleValue1 and it's fine. thz alot bro. :)

Comment: @bengoesboom By default, the detail label isn't shown at all. There are 4 values for the cell's style - Default, Subtitle, Value1, and Value2. Each one specifies a different layout. Only two - Value1 and Value2 - show the detail label on the right.

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];